# jax empty element in the parameters of neural network

Tags: autograd, jax

I am working on the implementation of a very small neural network. My network is as follows:

```
init_random_params, predict = stax.serial(
Dense(1024), Relu,
Dense(1024), Relu,
Dense(10), LogSoftmax)
```

I have initialized the neural network as follows:

```
_, init_params = init_random_params(rng, (-1, 28 * 28))
params = init_params
```

when I print the parameters of neural network it is a tuple of size 6. In fact `param[0]` and `param[2]` and `param[4]` are non-empty and consists of weight and bias of the corresponding layers. However, the rest of elements, i.e., `param[1]` and `param[3]` and `param[5]` are simply empty.

I would like to understand the reason behind this because it makes it difficult for me to implement some training algorithms that I am interested.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason you're using `stax`? Quoting from the `stax` [module docstring](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.example_libraries.stax.html):

> You likely do not mean to import this module! Stax is intended as an example library only. There are a number of other much more fully-featured neural network libraries for JAX, including [Flax](https://github.com/google/flax) from Google, and [Haiku](https://github.com/deepmind/dm-haiku) from DeepMind.

If you're having trouble creating neural networks with stax, you might try using an actively supported neural network library instead.

That said, I believe the reason there are no parameters in these entries is because `ReLu` and `LogSoftmax` do not require any parameters.

Comment: Thanks. I should try Flax. But it does not make sense to me. For instance, when I want to implement SGD it raises error

Comment: ```[(w - step_size * dw, b - step_size * db)
            for (w, b), (dw, db) in zip(params, grads)]```

Comment: Because some elements are empty, it gives me error.